# no intellisense visual studio code in Unity windows

Tags: unity, c#

It doesn't recognize object types and I can't use reference-finding. I have the Omnisharp plugin installed and updated.

Comment: I had similar issues in plain VS, and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/autocompletion-not-working-in-visual-studio) had the answer.

Comment: Please remember to [search for your question's keywords](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=unity+intellisense) before posting a new question. Common issues like this often have existing answers which can help you even faster, saving you the time of drafting a new question and waiting for responses.

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

- 1.install ms Sdk
- unity->preferences->External tools-> Use your Code editor
- install .net 4.7
- restart every thing And You are good to go

Comment: That's how i solved my problem of my favorite  editor i love vs code because of juicy plugin